# Can I apply for tourist visa

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, applications, deportation

I have been deported from UK two years ago, because I was charged and sentenced for criminal offence. Would there be any issue if I apply for schengn tourist visa

Comment: Can you apply? Yes, everyone can apply. What kind of issue are you afraid of? The worst thing that can happen is that you will be denied a visa.

Comment: @David Richerby Why so? Being deported from another country or sentenced for a criminal offence does not bar a person from travelling to Schengen. The application form doesn't even ask that.

Comment: @uberqe Sorry, my comment was vague. Deleted and reposted. You should probably post an expanded version of your comment.

Comment: @Neusser But being denied a visa would be a waste of quite a lot of money. It's pretty obvious that they're afraid that their criminal record will result in denial of the visa.

Comment: The UK operates SIS https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en so the deportation data may be available to Schengen countries even if the Schengen application itself does not specifically ask for it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes. But visas are sometimes denied without any criminal record and it's also a waste of money.

Comment: @Neusser Of course, but come on. Any reasonable person might think that having a criminal record will make it very likely that their visa application will be denied almost automatically. If that is the case, applying for a visa would be basically the same as flushing their money down the toilet. So they ask if it really is the case.

Comment: @DavidRicherby No, the question is "would there be any issue?" Not getting a visa is not an issue. And yes, having a criminal record drastically reduces chances to get a visa. It might be obvious for any reasonale person.

Comment: Please don't vote as a duplicate of a question that was closed as 'Unclear what you're asking'